# Internet Connection Sharing

Tags: windows-xp, connection-sharing, ad-hoc-network

I've  basic question on `Internet Connection Sharing` in Windows XP. I've a Internet Connection through LAN and I've created an Ad-hoc network that is supposed to share the internet connection.

Which connection should I enable "Internet Connection Sharing"? Is it on `LAN Connection' Settings > Advanced` of `Ad-hoc network Connections' Settings > Advanced` ?

Answer (score 1):

I would actually recommend just using the **Network Connection Wizard**.

Comment: But that doesn't give an option to share the connection.

Comment: It does all of that stuff for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable internet sharing on your LAN interface, to your WiFi interface.

So it's the former of your two options - "LAN connection settings" -> Advanced